Pulling data from Cisco Wireless Controller
since there is no api support for cisco wireless lan controllers, I am trying to use python to connect via cli and pull the data.
unfortunately cli output from cisco WLC is not well structured. I cannot use ansible at this point as I only have win10 LAB equipment.
this is the data that I am pulling from controller.

I am using netmiko library to pull the data and put into dictionary so I can manipulate and access however it is not working as intended.
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from netmiko import ConnectHandler, exceptions
import re

device= {
            'device_type': 'cisco_wlc_ssh',
            'ip': 'redacted',
            'username': 'redacted',
            'password': 'redacted',
            'port' : 22,
            "session_log":r'D:\Python Projects\Netmiko\WifiCLI\Netmiko_session_GNR_log',
            "session_log_file_mode": "append"
}

try:
    connect = ConnectHandler(**device)
    show_netuser_sum = connect.send_command("show netuser summary", expect_string=f'y/n')
    show_netuser_sum += connect.send_command_timing("y")
    show_netuser_sum = show_netuser_sum.strip().split("\n")
except (exceptions.ReadTimeout) as e:
    connect = ConnectHandler(**device)
    show_netuser_sum = connect.send_command("show netuser summary")
    show_netuser_sum = show_netuser_sum.strip().split("\n")

header_line = show_netuser_sum[3]
data_lines = show_netuser_sum[5:]

headers = re.split(r'\s{2,}', header_line.strip())

# Extract data
data = []
for line in data_lines:
    # Split the line based on multiple spaces
    split_line = re.split(r'\s{2,}', line.strip())
    
    if len(split_line) > len(headers):
        split_line[1] = ' '.join(split_line[1:3])
        split_line.pop(2)
        if len(split_line) > len(headers):
            split_line[3] = ' '.join(split_line[3:])
            split_line = split_line[:len(headers)]
    
    if len(split_line) < len(headers):
        split_line.insert(3, '')

    row_data = dict(zip(headers, split_line))
    data.append(row_data)

# Print the structured data
for row in data:
    print(row)

unfortunately the output is still messy 
as you see, lifetime and description is mixing up. I have 13 rows of users and some of them is coming up like that (like user bcook and its lifetime/description)
